# Redirect wrongly indexed Google pages to proper pages within my routes

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes

Google started indexing my site early, so some of the routes they have go to a nonexistant page, which throws a missing controller error.

Is there a way within my routes to explicitly redirect anything after a specific parameter to 301 redirect to the proper url?

Something like

```
<?
if ($this->params['wrongCategory']) {
$this->redirect('/properCategory');
}
?>
```

But ideally within my routes?

```
Router::connect('/wrongCategory/*', /*do a 301 redirect here */);
```

Comment: When doing redirects like this it's important to send the right HTTP status code and you won't achieve that using routing. .htaccess is the way as was previously suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it will be more efficient to make this permanent redirect through the file **.htaccess** in your root directory, something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^wrongCategory/(.*)$ /properCategory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Good call. I'll do that. You recommend me getting rid of this rule eventually?

Comment: Well, I don't know why Google is doing it wrong, but if you recently changed this URL, in some time you don't need this anymore. Just keep following the urls that google generated.